# Pipe from base64 not working well for avconv

Tags: audio, avconv

I got a 3gpp audio file that is stored in base 64 that I need to convert to wav.
Currently I got two step:

```
base64 -d test.txt > test.3gpp
avconv -i test.3gpp test.wav
```

But I would like to have just one step, to lower the number of disk IO I am going to do. I tried:

```
base64 -d test.txt | avconv -i pipe:0 test.wav
```

But I get:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x210cf40] stream 0, offset 0x20: partial file
```

Reading `man avconv` suggests that this is how to use the pipe, but clearly I am missing something. I am not an audio expert.

sample file, in base 64 is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhqax1ni4aolyi1/temp.txt?dl=0)

Here is the meta data when the process runs OK:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.3gpp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
  Duration: 00:00:32.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: amrnb, 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
Output #0, wav, to 'test.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
    ISFT            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (amrnb -> pcm_s16le)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
size=     511kB time=32.68 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:511kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.014917%
```

When it is not OK:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x210cf40] stream 0, offset 0x20: partial file
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
  Duration: 00:00:32.68, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: amrnb, 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
Output #0, wav, to 'test.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
    ISFT            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-14 14:16:19
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (amrnb -> pcm_s16le)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x210cf40] stream 0, offset 0x40: partial file
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead inf%
```

Comment: Are you certain the processing is streamable? Does `avconv` need to seek around the input to do its conversion?

Comment: @EtanReisner reading `man avconv` more closely points to the sentence: Note that some formats (typically MOV), require the output protocol to be seekable, so they will fail with the pipe output protocol.
https://libav.org/avconv.html#pipe  I am trying to understand now if 3gpp needs to be seekable

Comment: @EtanReisner thinking about that line again, I think the issue is only if the pipe is for the output.

Comment: That comment is about output, yes, but the idea applies to input as well. If `avconv` needs to seek around the input to convert then it can't do that from a pipe.

Comment: A sample base64 input file will be helpful.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I've added a link to a sample file in base 64. thank you.

Comment: `mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2`, etc is generally not pipe friendly. As for the disk I/O perhaps using tmpfs will be a solution.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I was not aware of tmpfs . looks like what I need. if you would put it in an answer I will mark it is answered. thank you.